# Oracle apex dynamic action, show related values without submitting a page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I searched internet a lot to solve my this problem, in oracle apex, In the below picture I have a table in the name of "tbl_group" which contains

> - group_code
> - member_name

I want that by selecting a group code from first column from `popup LOV` in the second column by clicking the `pop LOV`, it should show only the members who has that `group_code` and this action should happen without page refresh, because the user should continue selecting members.

[image: plz click here for the img]

Comment: This won't be a simple dynamic action since cascading LOVs are not yet supported in tabular forms. There are a couple of solutions out there you could evaluate, e.g. http://jaris.blogsite.org/apex/f?p=BLOG:READ:0::::ARTICLE:2914000346137910 and http://deneskubicek.blogspot.com.au/2008/04/cascading-select-list-in-tabular-form.html

Comment: tnk u Krishnan i solve this problem, using a dynamic action "on change"